# How to fix sounddevice.PortaudioError. Error opening RawStream: invalid sample rate [PaErrorCode -9997]

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying to install google assistant  on my Pi 3b+, and everything was going well, no errors, my mic and speakers are working, my .asoundrc is correct

```
pcm.!default {
  type asym
  capture.pcm "mic"
  playback.pcm "speaker"
}
pcm.mic {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "hw:1,0"
  }
}
pcm.speaker {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "hw:0,0"
  }
}
```

and I've followed a lot of tutorials and did exactly like them, also tried some other fixes online but none fix this.

Here is the whole message

```
INFO:root:Connecting to embeddedassistant.googleapis.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/env/bin/googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/pushtotalk.py", line 351, in main
    flush_size=audio_flush_size
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/audio_helpers.py", line 190, in __init__
    blocksize=int(block_size/2),  # blocksize is in number of frames.
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sounddevice.py", line 1264, in __init__
    **_remove_self(locals()))
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sounddevice.py", line 780, in __init__
    'Error opening {0}'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sounddevice.py", line 2572, in _check
    raise PortAudioError(errormsg, err)
sounddevice.PortAudioError: Error opening RawStream: Invalid sample rate [PaErrorCode -9997]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alright aftest testing  some stuff, I tried putting rate 16000 under pcm.speaker  and now it works

```
pcm.!default {
  type asym
  capture.pcm "mic"
  playback.pcm "speaker"
}
pcm.mic {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "hw:1,0"
  }
}
pcm.speaker {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "hw:0,0"
    rate 16000
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who still have this problem:

Make sure you edit the **/etc/asound.conf** file. I got stuck because I edited the **/home/pi/.asoundrc** file.